# Dynamic programmin code to calculate fibonacci number

Tags: dynamic

I am  not getting the result please  help me in this dynamic programming question

```
#include <stdio.h>
int fibbo_num(int n);

int main()
{
    int n;
    fibbo_num(3);

    return 0;
}
int fibbo_num(int n)
{
    int i;
    int Arr[n + 1];
    if(n==0||n==1){
        return Arr[n]=n ;
    }
   

    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        Arr[i] = Arr[i - 1] + Arr[i - 2];
    }
    return Arr[i];
    //printf("%d\n",Arr[i]);
}
```

I am expecting  result must come out .